# How to invoke Unix "script" command in Perl?

Tags: perl, unix, command

I'm sure this is an easy fix, but I need to use "script" (and not collect standard in/out/error) for my project.  I'm somewhat new to Perl, so please bear with me.

I have a Perl script that works fine.  When I run it I generally type `script > filename` before I run Perl.

```
$script > file.log
bash-3.2$ perl foobar.pl
```

This runs fine, and when I'm done I type exit or control D to stop the script and save the file.  All I'd like to do is incorporate the `script` command in Perl and then automatically capture the file when the program stops running (12-16 hours).  The problem I have is that is I call in `system("script > file.log");` and them call `system("perl foobar.pl");` it hangs at the `bash-3.2$` prompt.  The only way to get Perl to work is control D or exit, stopping the script function.

Anyone have any idea how to fix this?  While it's easy to start with script before invoking Perl, if I'm a mole and forget, I have to rerun the program (which takes a long time).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `system("script -c 'perl foobar.pl' file.log")`?